# Assignment using ":=" when calling a Python function. Is their documentation on this?

Tags: python

I came across the symbol ":=" in a Python snippet. Apparently it assigns to a variable, when calling a function.

```
import numpy
numpy.random.shuffle( x := [1, 2, 3, 4] )
# x is now created/overwritten
```

Is there any documentation on this ":=" symbol?

Comment: It is the [walrus operator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/)

Comment: @Tomerikoo The snippet in that question is pseudocode, so it's not a duplicate, but the answers are good!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called the "walrus operator" and it's used for [assignment expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#assignment-expressions). It's [new in Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions).

This is frankly not a good use of it since all it does is save writing `x` again, while making the code confusing (as you noticed, lol), and incompatible with Python 3.7-. Rewrite:

```
import numpy
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
numpy.random.shuffle(x)
```

See [PEP 572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) for more details and better examples, especially [this one](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#sysconfig-py).

Comment: Seriously from curiosity: isn't all walrus uses are pretty much "save one line of code"? I mean, you could always write the assignment separately. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Tomerikoo No, there are some situations where it saves **two** lines of code! :P But seriously, check out [this example](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#capturing-condition-values) from PEP 572. It's much cleaner with the walrus, especially the if-elif chain, which would otherwise have to be nested if-else's.

Comment: Oh right. User input validation is classic example of cleaner code. Nice!

Comment: Thanks! I can see some useful situations for this operator, but indeed, it could be  confusing too :-)